# Addresses of two consecutive buffers

Tags: buffer-overflow

I have two buffers declared one after the another, like this:

```
char A[256];
char B[32];
```

At first, I thought I could write whatever I wanted in B with a buffer overflow from A. However, some tests showed it is not possible, because the address of B is 32 bytes lower than A.

My question: why is B stocked before A, despite being defined after? Is there no way to rewrite it using A ?

Comment: I don't think that this is necessarily defined behavior, so one compiler may put it before, the other after.

Comment: It may even depend for the same compiler on whether the arrays have automatic or static duration...